# Exporting all selectable things to separate GLB files

Tags: export, gltf

I have a .glb model of the International Space Station which is splitted into multiple objects (each object is a single module/solar panel/etc.). Now I want to export every single selectable object to a separate .glb file. I tried to use a batch export plugin but it exported only objects listed in the scene tree in the upper-right region of the Blender window (only some smaller meshes), and it ignored all other objects (most modules). How can I export all them into separate objects without losing textures, UV coordinates and all other properties, without selecting every single of the 30+ objects and exporting it (which takes too much time and effort)?

[image: ISS]